# Listen to meta data firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am new to Firestore and learning things out. On my learning path, I have reached the section on [Events for meta data changes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#events-metadata-changes) in the Firebase documentation.

This is looking very useful but I am unable to understand how to test it. This is the code in documentation

```
db.collection("cities").doc("SF")
    .onSnapshot({
        // Listen for document metadata changes
        includeMetadataChanges: true
    }, function(doc) {
        // ...
    });
```

I added my simple update command to see what happens, it is updating every second. I want to understand what it is trying to give me back ? and in what case I can use it ? Why is it updating every second ?

```
 firebase.firestore().collection("cities").doc("DC")
    .onSnapshot({
        // Listen for document metadata changes
        includeMetadataChanges: true
    }, function(doc) {
        // ...
    var docRef = firebase.firestore().collection('cities').doc('DC');
     var updateTimestamp = docRef.update({
     timestamp: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
 });
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So actually you created modern infinite loop.

You subscribed to `snapshotChanges` of `DC` document (for data and metadata), so it means any change in the document you will receive it. And as soon as you run it for the first time, the current data comes as first time run subscription.

Then in subscribe, you update same document, it means again your subscription will be run, and again and again.

```
 firebase.firestore().collection("cities").doc("DC")
    .onSnapshot({includeMetadataChanges: true}, (docSnapshot) => {
        console.log(docSnapshot);
    });
```

Comment: can you alter my code so it just runs for only 1 time so that i can understand what i am getting..and secondly do shall i create a separate question as i  want to list the entries which are still offline on mysystem using `metadata.hasPendingWrites` , `collection name - cities` , `doc name - DC`

Comment: i saw that, it is returning object, i have edited my question, i think if i can reach till there, i will be able to use it completely. If you want i can add it as a separate question

Comment: @user2828442 I suggest don't mix the questions, regarding to offline submit a new one

Comment: alright added new question here- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60834041/how-do-i-get-the-records-which-are-offline-firestore

Comment: I suggest that all requests for free work (and on the other thread) are ignored.