# How to get the records which are offline in Firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to go offline and add 1 entry in `cities` collection using this code below:

```
 firebase.firestore().collection("cities").doc("NY").set({
   name: "Los Angeles",
   state: "CA",
   country: "USA"
  capital: false
 })
 .then(function() {
    console.log("Document successfully written!");
 })
 .catch(function(error) {
    console.error("Error writing document: ", error);
 });
```

How do I add the above code inside

`firebase.firestore().disableNetwork().then(function() {` and `.onSnapshot({includeMetadataChanges: true}, (docSnapshot) => {
    console.log(docSnapshot);
});`

so that I can read all docs are offline from collection `cities` as I have to show icon in front of them.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "add the above code inside". Are you just saying that, when you perform a query, you want to know which documents have been written locally but not synchronized with the server yet?

Comment: yes you got it, i want a query which returns me list of docs which are  written locally but not synchronized with the server yet

Comment: Hi user2828442. I've edited a lot of chatty material from your questions in the past, and you will have received the notifications from the Stack Overflow platform. Some of your material has a needy, begging quality, and suggests you think that displays of helplessness will cause people to pity your situation and/or feel coerced into the social obligation of assisting the less fortunate. This is not appropriate behaviour for a volunteer platform. Please stick to technical writing.

Answer (score 0):

Firestore doesn't offer a type of query that returns only documents written to local cache but have not been synchronized.

The best you can do is make the query normally, and inspect the [metadata](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot#metadata) of each [DocumentSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot) object.  The [SnapshotMetadata](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.SnapshotMetadata) will tell you if the document [hasPendingWrites](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.SnapshotMetadata#haspendingwrites) that are not yet synchronized with the server.

Comment: exactly. how do i include document snapshot while adding ? and what will be the query to search

Comment: I don't understand your question.  There is no different query.  You have to check the fields on the objects I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: you mean, adding query will be same , i dont need to include anything special in my add query. If yes, then what is the query to search and get what is offline ?, so sorry i am trying to understand the docs but i am bit confused

Comment: As I said in my answer, "Firestore doesn't offer a type of query that returns only documents written to local cache but have not been synchronized".  You have to do a query as normal, then look at each document snapshot to see if it was fully written or not.

Comment: i have understood this, can you with your answer provide example ? Again saying i have understood what you have guided but unable to code it

Comment: This thread has been pointed to [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60830983), which also features requests for free work. They will hopefully be ignored here too.